# jquery function not found inside of event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

this is driving me crazy.  if you look at the comments, the slider is accessible and working inside of the document.ready event.

however, the exact same line of code doesn't work in the toggle

this is just one example but i cannot manipulate that slider inside ANY events....whats going on?

https://jsfiddle.net/w3zv5t0s/11/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tv").load("tv.php");
  //WORKS HERE
  $("#dimmer-3").val(10).slider("refresh");
  $('.toggle').on("slidestop", function() {
    //NOT HERE
    $("#dimmer-3").val(1).slider("refresh");
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Mobile -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>


<select class='toggle' id='3' data-role='slider' data-itemID='3'>
  <option value='ON'>On</option>
  <option value='OFF' selected='selected'>Off</option>
</select>

<input class='dimmerSlider' id="dimmer-3" type='range' value='15' min='0' max='15' step='1' data-highlight='true' data-itemID='sl3' />

<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
  <h3>TV LED</h3>
  <div id="tv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think it is working in the fiddle, for slider you need to include the plugin library and need to initialize it

Comment: which is the plugin used?

Comment: oops...ive just updated the jfiddle to the plugins im using, https://jsfiddle.net/w3zv5t0s/11/....i think the problem is the mix of jquery and jquery mobile somehow.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/a7v4wacu/1/ - jQuery library need to be included before the jquery-mobile

Comment: its like that in my live code but it still doesnt work....`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).slider is not a function` -  ive updated my post with my entire code

Comment: that code was stripped out from a php page that dynamically generates the rest of the elements...the ids and everything are examples pulled from it.  is it possible that it's not working because the elements are dynamic and not hardcoded?  but why would it work outside of the slide function?

Comment: *dynamically generates the rest of the elements....* If the elements are added after your jquery, thats likely the issue, try `$(document).on("slidestop",".toggle" function() {  $("#dimmer-3").val(1).slider("refresh"); });`

Comment: with cdn files they are just fine... I don't think dynamic elements are creating the error... if you want to test it remove the dynamic code and have a static markup and test whether it is working

Comment: i figured it out...so i have a div that has a .load() function.  that div is on another part of the page...any idea why a .load would break this functionality?  especially when it has nothing to do with the location of the input markers?  the sliders are loaded on page load, NOT in the div called with .load()...ive updated original page

Comment: Show the load code OR create a new question and put your "answer" in this one and reference it in the new question